# CompilationTestHelper is either not found or its access discouraged

Tags: java, eclipse, xtext

I want to write some tests for my compiler but can't get past an error.

I'm following an example from '*Implementing DSL with Xtext and Xtend*' by L. Bettini (great book btw). I've downloaded the code for the '`entities`' DSL from https://github.com/LorenzoBettini/packtpub-xtext-book-examples and the tests in `EntitiesGenerator.xtend` work great.

If I write a test for the default DSL (`MyDsl`) using the same code, I've got an error:

- `org.eclipse.xtext.xbase.compiler.CompilationTestHelper cannot be resolved to a type`.

or, if I add `org.eclipse.xtext.xbase.junit (2.4.1)` to the list of required plug-ins, I get

- `Discouraged access: The type CompilationTestHelper is not accessible due to restriction on required project org.xtext.example.myDsl.tests`

I can allow access to it, but then get a runtime error anyway. If I try to add `org.eclipse.xtext.xbase.lib` as well, only `org.eclipse.xtext.xbase.lib.source` appears in the list. I don't know it that matters. In any case, adding it doesn't change anything.

What do I need to do to make it work?

I'm using Juno with Xtext 2.4.1., Java 1.7.

The content of the test class:

```java
package org.xtext.example.myDsl.tests

import com.google.inject.Inject
import org.eclipse.xtext.junit4.InjectWith
import org.eclipse.xtext.junit4.XtextRunner
import org.eclipse.xtext.xbase.compiler.CompilationTestHelper // error here
import org.xtext.example.myDsl.MyDslInjectorProvider
import org.junit.Test
import org.junit.runner.RunWith

@RunWith(typeof(XtextRunner))
@InjectWith(typeof(MyDslInjectorProvider))
class MyDslGeneratorTest {

    @Inject extension CompilationTestHelper

    @Test
    def void testGeneratedCode() {
        '''
    Hello some1!
    Hello some2!
        '''.assertCompilesTo(
        '''some content''')
    }
}
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: FYI - messages such as "X is not accessible due to restriction on required project Y" normally mean that your project is configured to use a strict definition of what a "normal" Java runtime contains and it doesn't like the idea that you've allow access to a JAR that others users may not have. I.e. under project properties you'll have something like "jre7" rather than a specific VM on your local machine.

Comment: I'm not sure I'm following, I'm afraid. If I compare the properties of `org.example.entities.tests` (whose source doesn't show the warning) and those of `org.xtext.example.myDsl.test`, the libraries and the order and export are identical.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the xtext guys mark stuff that may be changed NOT as api. this is why you get this warning.
it should work anyway. (although it is meant to be used for xbase languages only)

P.S: you have to add a dependency to jdt.core too

Comment: Adding jdt.core did the trick, thanks. The test runs without crashing. The warning is still there.